# Activating an <option> when clicked on a button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to activate an

```
<option>
```

when i click on a button i tried it for long but wasn't able to do it. This is my code.  http://jsfiddle.net/aatqnbj7/2/

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Click</button>
 <select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
float:left;
width:130px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

Java is fine but it would be really great if it can be done using css 
It is fine if it only stays for a second like in active state

Comment: You want on click open select box or activate default desavled  selectbox?

Comment: @Harutyun i want both the option to drop down when i click the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery('#clickedBtn').click(function(){
var size = $('.select option').size();
    if (size != $(".select").prop('size')) {
        $(".select").prop('size', size);
    } else {
        $(".select").prop('size', 1);
    }

})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aatqnbj7/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot i know that it is too much to ask but can you do it with javascript?

Comment: Thanks...got what i wanted